# MIPS saving address of array to a variable

Tags: arrays, mips, memory-address

```
.data

    Stackarray: .word 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 
    TopStack: .word 0
    BottomStack: .word 0

.text

    la $s0, Stackarray  # stores the beginning of array into $s0
    la $a1, 4($s0)      # stores address of second element of array into $a1
    sw $a1, TopStack
```

TopStack is supposed to hold the value of an address, but when I print TopStack it comes up with a huge number: "268500996". 
I'm just trying to verify whether TopStack holds the value of the address of the second element of the array. The true value should be "10010004"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you think that the "true value" is 1001004?

I added the following to the end of your code

```
#print data in TopStack
lw $a0, TopStack
li $v0, 1
syscall

#new line
li $a0, 10
li $v0, 11
syscall

#print address of Stackarray
la $a0, Stackarray
li $v0, 1
syscall
```

And I got:

```
268500996
268500992
```

So everything looks in line to me.

Comment: well TopStack is supposed to hold the address to the second element of the array, which has the address "10010004"

Comment: No, it doesn't. It's 4 after the first element, ie `268500996`. Why do you think it has some other address?

Comment: oh okay I just realized 268500996 is 10010004 in decimal form...That completely skipped my mind. So if I decrement 268500996 by four, that would mean the TopStack would point to the '0' of Stackarray? How would I go about implementing saving a new value to the address of that '0' then? Essentially pushing a new value onto it?

Comment: Ah good call, didn't pick up that connection either. I'm not sure I understand your question, but after using `la` you can just use `sw` to store to the address, which would be the first element of Stackarray